# Developer menu not displaying on android emulator react native

Tags: android, react-native, emulation

I have tried doing the following on both Android studio & Genymotion emulators to solve this:

1. Pressing cmd+M, Fn+f2
2. adb shell input keyevent 82, adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU
3. reinstalled emulators

Is there any other ways to solve this issue? I am not sure what settings I need to have this running.

Comment: make sure that you installed build using `react-native run-android` not using `react-native run-android --variant=release` , developer menu will work only in debug build.

Comment: hi, I normally use ./gradlew installDebug to build the app into the emulator. But I tried using react-native run-android anyway. it didn't work too. @Aravindh

Comment: did you find any solution?? @JeremyPek

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio check correct version of mode. You cannot debug in release mode. Just press on Active Build Variant and choose debug mode
[image: In Android Studio]